# Close modal inline dialog by clicking on button in sub-region and prevent it from re-opening

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, oracle-apex-5.1

I've created a region, let's call it `Notifications` with `Static ID: P1_NOTIFICATIONS`, set its `Template` to `Inline Dialog` and added a sub-region called `row-01` without any `Static ID`.

`row-01` has a button `OK` with `P1_MODAL_OK` ID and the following `Behavior`: `Action: Redirect to URL`, `Target: javascript:apex.navigation.modal.close(true,["P1_NOTIFICATIONS"])` or `Target: javascript:apex.navigation.modal.close(true)`.

Neither JS API calls seem to work, modal doesn't close on clicking my button.

Tried also a dynamic action to `Hide` the `P1_NOTIFICATIONS` region, but it only hides its content, doesn't close the modal itself with all the overlays and stuff. The header and empty body are still visible.

Also there's an `[x] Close` button in the header, but I need to hide it. I also can't find its action, the script it calls to close the modal inline dialog region.

How to close the modal from my `P1_MODAL_OK` custom button? And how to catch the action triggered by the `[x]` button from modals header?

**EDIT 1:** `openModal('P1_NOTIFICATIONS')` works as well as `closeModal('P1_NOTIFICATIONS')`. The second solves my problem.

Comment: Did you try 'Close Dialog' Dynamic action on the button?

Comment: @Blurryface yeah, thanks. Couldn't find it for the first time for some reason. Also there is no mention on the internet for that method.

Comment: @Blurryface But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To close modal `inline dialog` region, create a `Redirect to URL` button with the following call in target: `javascript:closeModal('P1_NOTIFICATIONS')`, where `P1_NOTIFICATIONS` is region's `Static ID`.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me, i Created a dynamic action on the button with the  action **Close Region** and then under affected element i selected the region for the inline dialog